# Diaphragm + rotary vane vacuum pump and oil vapor

Tags: experimental-physics, vacuum

It is known that rotary vane pump will cause oil vapor to the vacuum, as it requires oil for operation. On the other side, diaphragm pump does not require oil but offers much weaker vacuum.

Is it possible to use diaphragm pump on the first stage, and rotary vane pump on the second? Will diaphragm pump be able to pump to some 1-100Pa pressure? Will it help to reduce vacuum contamination / slightly improve vacuum?

PS. Surely turbomolecular pump will offer much better performance on the first stage, but it is much more expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of following 2 methods as a trap for the reflux oil from rotary pump, when I had read this. I think that most reflux oil can be trapped by them. But I don't know whether all reflux oil can be trapped completely.

1. Foreline trap

   This is a trap using molecular sieve. I think that this can be bought for hundreds of dollars.
2. Cold trap

   This is a trap by cooling the evacuating passage. I have ever made this trap by myself before. At that time, I have used ice and liquid nitrogen. Although those could be used, in the case of long time operation, the foreline trap is more comfortable.

Both traps are used by installing to between the rotary pump and the vacuum chamber. By this, the chamber can be evacuated directly gases from atmospheric pressure.